# How can I groupby and calculate the date difference from a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
df = id -    date
     ps1  - 2020-01-2
     ps1  - 2020-01-3
     ps2  - 2020-01-3
     ps2  - 2020-01-5
```

I would like to get output like

```
output = id - date_diff
         ps1  - 1
         ps2  - 2
```

How can i group the ids and calculate the data differences ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert `date` to datetime, `diff` and `drop` all the nulls.

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
    df["date_diff"] = df.groupby("id")["date"].diff().astype('timedelta64[D]')
    df[df.date_diff.notnull()]
```

Answer (score 2):

First coerce your `date` column to datetime, and then `groupby` and `diff`:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df["date_diff"] = df.groupby("id")["date"].diff()
print (df.drop_duplicates("id",keep="last"))

    id       date date_diff
1  ps1 2020-01-03    1 days
3  ps2 2020-01-05    2 days
```